# Adding own map to/over MapKit iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, geolocation, mapkit, core-location

I'm doing an app with specific maps and I would like to add those on top of the regular MapKit ones (Gmaps). Could anyone please tell me how exactly I could do that so I could use my own maps?

Comment: Good question. I don't know if you can. What sort of maps? What format are they in? What do you want to do with them? Just show them? Add Pins? Search functionality?

Comment: Just some png's I want to use in order to track myself inside my house.

Comment: Yes :) why? But it would be quite useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your looking for but sounds similar.
http://shawnsbits.com/blog/2010/12/23/mapkit-overlays-session-1-overlay-map/